# Why did Jesus say, "Do not touch me"?

Tags: gospel-of-john, words-of-jesus, resurrection-of-jesus, thomas-apostle, mary-magdalene

John 20:17:

> Jesus said, "Do not touch me, for I have not yet returned to the Father. Go instead to my brothers and tell them, 'I am returning to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God.'"

Why did Jesus not want Mary to touch him, remembering that he allowed Thomas to touch him before he went to heaven?

Comment: More-modern translations have either "do not hold on to me" or "do not cling to me" or variants thereof. Hence, this is a different kind of "touch" than when Thomas (almost) touched Jesus. It's still a good question though.

Comment: [Both of these pages have great commentary](http://books.google.com/books?id=DqU_AAAAYAAJ&dq=jesus%20the%20christ&pg=PA682#v=onepage&q=touch%20me%20not&f=false) about that occasion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason Jesus said this has been the subject of debate. One common belief is that He didn't want her to ***tarry*** there, that it was more of a "now is not the time" statemen. Example:

> **Clarke's Commentary on the Bible**
>
> Touch me not - Μη μου ἁπτου, Cling not to me. Ἁπτομαι has this sense
>   in Job 31:7, where the Septuagint use it for the Hebrew דבק dabak,
>   which signifies to cleave, cling, stick, or be glued to. From Matthew
>   28:9, it appears that some of the women held him by the feet and
>   worshipped him. This probably Mary did; and our Lord seems to have
>   spoken to her to this effect: "Spend no longer time with me now: I am
>   not going immediately to heaven - you will have several opportunities
>   of seeing me again: but go and tell my disciples, that I am, by and
>   by, to ascend to my Father and God, who is your Father and God also.
>   Therefore, let them take courage."

Another view:

> **Vincent's Word Studies**
>
> Touch me not (μή μοῦ ἅπτου)
>
> The verb, primarily, means to fasten to. Hence it implies here, not a
>   mere momentary touch, but a clinging to. Mary thought that the old
>   relations between her Lord and herself were to be renewed; that the
>   old intercourse, by means of sight, sound, and touch, would go on as
>   before. Christ says, "the time for this kind of intercourse is over.
>   Henceforth your communion with me will be by faith through the Spirit.
>   This communion will become possible through my ascending to the
>   Father."

And another, similar to the others, but emphasizing "There are other things to do right now".

> **People's New Testament**
>
> 20:17 Touch me not. She was probably about to clasp his feet. She is
>   told to discharge a higher duty: to go to the brethren with the glad
>   story.

Answer (score 2):

The passage does not make clear how Mary is touching him. H.C.G. Moule speculates that she likely grabbed his arm or hand to try and verify his physical existence. Biblical scholar Raymond Brown has listed a wide array of explanations for his injunction:

- Jesus' wounds were still sore so he did not like being touched
- Kraft proposes that the prohibition was because it was against ritual
  to touch a dead body
- Chrysostom and Theophylact argue that Jesus was asking that more
  respect be shown to him. This theory is sometimes linked to the
  notion that while it was not appropriate for a woman to touch Jesus
  it was fine for a man like Thomas.
- C. Spicq sees the resurrected Jesus as the equivalent of one of the
  Jewish high priests who should not be sullied by physical contact
- Kastner, who believes Christ returned in the nude, believes the
  prohibition was so that Mary would not be tempted by Jesus' body
- Mary should not touch Jesus because she should not need physical
  proof of the resurrection but should trust in her faith.
- Bultmann sees the phrase as an indirect way of saying that the
  resurrected Jesus was not at this point tangible.
- According to Moule Jesus' intervention is not a prohibition on being
  touched, but rather an assurance that the touching is not needed for
  he had not yet returned to the Father and was still firmly here on
  Earth. His use of the present tense is said to mean that he should
  not be touched just at this moment, but could be touched in future.
- Some link it with the next verse stating that they should be read as
  one to say "don't touch me instead go tell my disciples of the news"
- In John Calvin's commentary he argues that Jesus did not forbid
  simple touching, but rather that Jesus had no problems until the
  women began to cling to him as though they were trying to hold him in
  the corporeal world at which point Jesus told them to let go. Some
  translations thus use touch for the seemingly permitted actions in
  Mark and cling for the action Jesus chides Mary for in this verse.
- Barrett mentions the possibility that between this verse and John
  20:22 Jesus fully ascends to heaven

There are also a number of scholars who have proposed alternate translations. These are not based on direct linguistic evidence but are rather attempts to synchronize the phrase with other parts of the Bible. There is also some evidence that the wording may have been mangled.

- Some scholars eliminate the negative leaving the phrase as "touch
  me," implying that Jesus is telling Mary to verify his physical form
- W.E.P. Cotter and others argue that the text should actually read "do
  not fear me"
- W.D. Morris believes it should read "do not fear to touch me"

Source: [John 20:17 (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_20:17)

Another possibility is that women were considered ritually unclean when menstruating:

> Through much of its history, especially in the West, women were
>   considered ritually unclean. According to Jewish tradition, a woman's
>   monthly flow of blood put her regularly into a state of ritual
>   defilement. Similar taboos against menstruation existed in pagan Greek
>   and Roman circles. Through their anti-sex mania, the Fathers of the
>   Church aggravated the fears of women's ritual uncleanness. Church
>   leaders were anxious that such uncleanness might defile the holiness
>   of the church building, the sanctuary and mainly the altar. In a
>   climate that increasingly looked on all aspects of sex and procreation
>   as tainted with sin, theologians considered that an ‘unclean creature’
>   like a woman could not be entrusted with the care of God's sacred
>   realities. Prohibitions based on the presumed ‘ritual uncleanness’ of
>   women have remained in official Church Law for the last 700 years.

Source: [Women were considered Ritually Unclean](http://www.womenpriests.org/traditio/unclean.asp)

> The first two references to menstruation can be found in the Book of
>   Genesis. First in describing the patriarch Abraham and the fact that
>   his wife Sarah had reached the age of menopause, "Now Abraham and
>   Sarah were old, advanced in age; it had ceased to be with Sarah after
>   the way of women." The second occurs when Rachel tells her father
>   Laban that she cannot come to meet him since she was in the seclusion
>   that was mandatory for menstruating women: "And [Rachel] said to her
>   father [Laban], 'Let not my lord be angry that I cannot rise before
>   you, for the way of women is upon me.'" Explicit references to
>   menstruation can be found twice in the writings of the prophet
>   Ezekiel. He writes of the ritual impurity that menstruation brings
>   about in a woman and all she comes into contact with during that
>   specified time—"[A man is righteous] if he does not eat upon the
>   mountains or lift up his eyes to the idols of the house of Israel,
>   does not defile his neighbor's wife or approach a woman in her time of
>   impurity."  "Son of man, when the house of Israel dwelt in their own
>   land, they defiled it by their ways and their doings; their conduct
>   before me was like the uncleanness of a woman in her impurity." But
>   the most substantial scriptural text, the one that deems women
>   ritually impure for the interval of time surrounding her period is
>   Leviticus 15. This chapter deals with unclean discharges from the
>   genitals in both men and women. The first half speaks of various forms
>   of seminal and venereal emissions and men, and the second of the flow
>   of blood and menses in women. I quote that section, Leviticus 15:19-30
>   in full:    v. 19 When a woman has a discharge of blood which is her
>   regular discharge from her body, she shall be in her impurity for
>   seven days, and whoever touches her shall be unclean until the
>   evening. 20 And everything upon which she lies during her impurity
>   shall be unclean; everything also upon which she sits shall be
>   unclean. 21 And whoever touches her bed shall wash his clothes, and
>   bathe himself in water, and be unclean until the evening. 22 And
>   whoever touches anything upon which she sits shall wash his clothes,
>   and bathe himself in water, and be unclean until the evening; 23
>   whether it is the bed or anything upon which she sits, when he touches
>   it, he shall be unclean until the evening. 24 And if any man lies with
>   her, and her impurity is on him, he shall be unclean seven days, and
>   every bed on which he lies shall be unclean. 25 If a woman has a
>   discharge of blood for many days, not at the time of her impurity, or
>   if she has a discharge beyond the time of her impurity, all the days
>   of the discharge she shall continue in uncleanness; as in the days of
>   her impurity, she shall be unclean. 26 Every bed on which she lies,
>   all the days of her discharge, shall be to her as the bed of her
>   impurity, and everything on which she sits shall be unclean, as in the
>   uncleanness of her impurity. 27 And whoever touches these things shall
>   be unclean, and shall wash his clothes, and bathe himself in water,
>   and be unclean until the evening. 28 But if she is cleansed of her
>   discharge, she shall count for herself seven days, and after that she
>   shall be clean. 29 And on the eighth day she shall take two
>   turtledoves or two young pigeons, and bring them to the priest, to the
>   door of the tent of meeting.       30 And the priest shall offer one
>   for a sin offering and the other for a burnt offering, and the priest
>   shall make atonement for her before the LORD for her unclean
>   discharge.

Source: [University of Dayton](http://campus.udayton.edu/mary/questions/yq/yq195.html)

Answer (score 1):

Jesus had just completed his main task of taking on his person the sins of all the world. He had become God's perfect sacrifice. As a result, he needed to be purified. That could only be completed by his father. Why did this have to be done face to face? The Bible doesn't say. But given the intimate nature of the Father, Son and Spirit relationship, this meeting seems to have been necessary. Until Jesus had been cleansed of this burden, He could not allow anyone to come in contact with him. As fulfilling his role as Most High Priest, He must present the sacrifice, Himself, to God in order for the sacrifice to be consummated. This expressed the nature of temple sacrifices in which the High Priest would burn the sacrifice so it could symbolically be purified and ascend to God. Once done, Jesus could then allow Thomas, for instance, to touch his wounds and also explains why he would not allow Mary to touch him in any manner.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help. Nice, logical answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that Jesus, newly resurrected, showed himself before the Ascension. Given such an otherworldly endeavour, it may well be that human contact would have defiled him; and as such, was not permitted until after he had been with the Father. This would make sense given the women's penchant for falling at his feet and holding on for dear life. In Mary's case, it would have been her first inclination after having recognized her "Teacher". To read more into it dilutes the practical humanity of the encounter in favour of some theological exercise. It is possible that her exclamation of "teacher," and Jesus' subsequent admonition not to touch him, renders a transformative answer to Jesus' initial question, "who are you looking for"? She may have thus come to the correct understanding of his true nature—and confirms it by exclaiming that she had seen the Lord, *not* the Teacher, in the following verse.

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you showed, with sources, that it doesn't merely reflect your own analysis.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).